# How to check if all my SQL Server stored procedures are encrypted or not in one shot?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Is there any way to check whether all my stored procedures are encrypted or not in one shot?

I know to view the procedure's definition I get a message telling me that it's encrypted.

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'StoredProcedureName';
```

But I have a lot of stored procedures (1000+) so is there a better way to check 1 shot for all the stored procedures?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? I am very confident that `sp_helptext` does not exist in MySQL.

Comment: Cross site duplicate candidate: [How to query the names of encrypted stored procedures?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15100/how-to-query-the-names-of-encrypted-stored-procedures)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the [`sys.sql_modules` system view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-sql-modules-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

```sql
SELECT
    p.name,
    IsEncrypted = CAST(CASE WHEN m.definition IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit)
FROM sys.procedures p
JOIN sys.sql_modules m ON m.object_id = p.object_id
WHERE m.definition IS NULL
```

Alternatively, you can check the object property ([kudos to @AaronBertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/15101/220697))

```sql
SELECT
    name,
    IsEncrypted = OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'IsEncrypted')
FROM sys.procedures;
```

Comment: Might need to distinguish between system/builtin procedures and user-defined procedures.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is truly are *all* the SPs encrypted then the following code will handle it:

```
select case when exists
  ( select 42 from sys.procedures where ObjectProperty( object_id, 'IsEncrypted' ) = 0 and [type] = 'P' ) then 'No'
  else 'Yes' end as AllSPsEncrypted;
```